# UITableView problem in iPhone os 3.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created application in iPhone OS 2.2.1 which contains one table view and text view .

Whole application is working fine in all iPhone OS version except 3.0.

In iPhone OS 3.0 when I press next button then table view reloads so while reloading it shows some line in between the cells.

So can any one suggest me what will be the problem in OS 3.0?

Code on next button:

```
lblNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",Count,QUESTION]; 
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES]; 
[tblView reloadData]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Think you are going to have to show us some code - perhaps even a screen shot. What does your next button do - can you show the selector behind the button - the problem must be related to this event.

Comment: Seeing the same thing happening. I force an reloadData, and every once in a while some rows stay empty. Presumably table behaviour changed because there are more "targeted" ways to reload table data in OS 3.0?

Comment: code on next button:

lblNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",Count,QUESTION];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
   
[tblView reloadData];
   
[UIView commitAnimations];

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code, so I'm only guessing. But in the SDK OS 3.0 there were some changes in the `UITableViewCell` class. You don't use the `text` field anymore. Instead you change the text of the label contained in the cell, with `textLabel.text`.